# creating folders and an .exe file on Java

Tags: java, directory, executable

Hey guys I am developing a project in java for someone and I had some couple of questions about it. In this project, I will create a lot of image files, like 1000 or more, and I will need to have an executable for it, so my question is:

How can I make it have an executable that, when someone clicks on it, it installs itself on the computer (like on the following directory for example: C:/User/Programs/MyProject), and after that, how can I make it create another folder (called "pictures") where every file created on the project could be saved on.

Thanks for your attention guys.

Comment: creating folder in java is not a difficult thing, you can find a lot of answer in Stack overflow or google. the other part I do not understand, what do you mean you will need to have an executable? do you mean you want your java code to become as .exe file?

Comment: Not everyone on StackOverflow is a guy :)

Comment: Yah, my major problem with this algorithm was how could I make an executable file for it. it could be as an .exe or simply as a JAR file, as long as it could install the program on the computer, creating a folder for it in the process. 

For the "not everyone is a guy" I know that rofl =p, but it's common to say "hey guys" even when there are girls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a native executable have a look at [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net) or to create an installer for example here [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)

Folders can be created with the Java Standard API: [Creating and Reading Directories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look into this.